# Partial application in ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Is it possible to simplify this expression in a single statement ?

```
const _readFile = R.curry(fs.readFile);
const _readFile2 = _readFile(R.__, 'UTF-8', R.__);
```

Comment: You mean `const _readFile2 = R.curry(fs.readFile)(R.__, 'UTF-8', R.__)`?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. Something like 
https://github.com/plaid/async-problem/blob/0ea31b01eabf9a2cdb22bad112aee37e96325524/common/read-file-callback.js

Comment: @kay: that second `R.__` should not be needed.  It's meaningless as a final argument.

Comment: @FlorianF: the suggestion from kay is quite close to the Sanctuary one.  The only difference is that Sanctuary's curry also allows you to initially bind some parameters.  In Ramda that has to be done with a second call.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Do you mind writing it as an answer so I can mark this question as resolved ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this, but it's not so nice

```
const _readFile = compose(apply(__, [__, 'UTF-8', __]), curry)(readfile)
```

I'd personally learn towards

```
const _readFile = curry((file, cb) => readfile(file, 'UTF-8', cb))
```